# How add in Android Studio a popupmenu to application icon on android desktop?

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, icons, desktop

How add in Android Studio a popupmenu to application icon on android desktop?

[Example popupmenu from apk Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NglH2.png)

Comment: Those are app shortcuts: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! Shortcuts it works :)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts

Comment: @mih I was too slow :) I coded from the same documentation. Maybe my answer cannot help you anymore, but hopefully others. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you set the resource of your `shortcuts.xml`.

Like that in your `<activity android:name="Main">` with `<meta.data .../>`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.myapplication">
  <application ... >
    <activity android:name="Main">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                 android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" /> 
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Now you need to define the `shortcuts.xml` itself (I made this with you Chrome example):

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <shortcut
    android:shortcutId="new_tab"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/new_tab_icon"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/new_tab_shortcut_short_label1"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/new_tab_shortcut_long_label1"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/new_tab_disabled_message1"> <!-- create a String in strings.xml -->
    <intent
      android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
      android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ChromeActivity" />
    <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
         here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
         they launch this shortcut. -->
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.new_tab" />
  </shortcut>

<shortcut
        android:shortcutId="new_incognito_tab"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/new_tab_incognito_icon"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/new_incognito_tab_shortcut_short_label1"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/new_incognito_tab_shortcut_long_label1"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/new_incognito_tab_disabled_message1">
        <intent
          android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
          android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
          android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ChromeActivity" />
        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.new_incognito_tab" />
      </shortcut>
      <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
    </shortcuts>
```